# jqueryui dialog: width not calculate properly when resizing quickly from left side

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

A jqueryui dialog is placed at the ***right edge*** of window, when I ***quickly resize*** the dialog from the left side, the dialog's width was set incorretly. what I mean quickly resize here is, move the mouse fast and then quickly release the mouse, I will explain later the reason of doing this.

To make my word more clearly, I have created a jsfiddle:    https://jsfiddle.net/sangelee/hw62erug/6/embedded/result/

You can try yourself what I have done in the jsfiddle, but remember you should first put the dialog at the right edge of the container:
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

In the jqueryui source code, the following snippet is executed when resizing the dialog:

```
resize: function( event ) {
    var woset, hoset, isParent, isOffsetRelative,
        that = $( this ).resizable( "instance" ),
        o = that.options,
        co = that.containerOffset,
        cp = that.position,
        pRatio = that._aspectRatio || event.shiftKey,
        cop = {
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        },
        ce = that.containerElement,
        continueResize = true;

    if ( ce[ 0 ] !== document && ( /static/ ).test( ce.css( "position" ) ) ) {
        cop = co;
    }

    if ( cp.left < ( that._helper ? co.left : 0 ) ) {
        that.size.width = that.size.width +
            ( that._helper ?
                ( that.position.left - co.left ) :
                ( that.position.left - cop.left ) );

        if ( pRatio ) {
            that.size.height = that.size.width / that.aspectRatio;
            continueResize = false;
        }
        that.position.left = o.helper ? co.left : 0;
    }

    if ( cp.top < ( that._helper ? co.top : 0 ) ) {
        that.size.height = that.size.height +
            ( that._helper ?
                ( that.position.top - co.top ) :
                that.position.top );

        if ( pRatio ) {
            that.size.width = that.size.height * that.aspectRatio;
            continueResize = false;
        }
        that.position.top = that._helper ? co.top : 0;
    }

    isParent = that.containerElement.get( 0 ) === that.element.parent().get( 0 );
    isOffsetRelative = /relative|absolute/.test( that.containerElement.css( "position" ) );

    if ( isParent && isOffsetRelative ) {
        that.offset.left = that.parentData.left + that.position.left;
        that.offset.top = that.parentData.top + that.position.top;
    } else {
        that.offset.left = that.element.offset().left;
        that.offset.top = that.element.offset().top;
    }

    woset = Math.abs( that.sizeDiff.width +
        (that._helper ?
            that.offset.left - cop.left :
            (that.offset.left - co.left)) );

    hoset = Math.abs( that.sizeDiff.height +
        (that._helper ?
            that.offset.top - cop.top :
            (that.offset.top - co.top)) );

    if ( woset + that.size.width >= that.parentData.width ) {
        that.size.width = that.parentData.width - woset;
        if ( pRatio ) {
            that.size.height = that.size.width / that.aspectRatio;
            continueResize = false;
        }
    }

    if ( hoset + that.size.height >= that.parentData.height ) {
        that.size.height = that.parentData.height - hoset;
        if ( pRatio ) {
            that.size.width = that.size.height * that.aspectRatio;
            continueResize = false;
        }
    }

    if ( !continueResize ) {
        that.position.left = that.prevPosition.left;
        that.position.top = that.prevPosition.top;
        that.size.width = that.prevSize.width;
        that.size.height = that.prevSize.height;
    }
}
```

In the code above, there is a conditional statement:

```
if ( woset + that.size.width >= that.parentData.width ) {
        that.size.width = that.parentData.width - woset;
        if ( pRatio ) {
            that.size.height = that.size.width / that.aspectRatio;
            continueResize = false;
        }
    }
```

The `woset` was the element's previous `$(element).offset().left`, but the `that.size.width` is the element's current new width, why the `woset` used the previous value but not the current offset, or just use `event.pageX`?

I have tried that, if `woset` was replaced by `event.pageX`, or remove the statement `that.size.width = that.parentData.width - woset;`, the flickering of the dialog's right side that I showed in the jsfiddle won't happen, and the dialog's resizing behavior still works well. So why add this conditional statement?

If the dialog was not placed at the right edge of window, the conditional statement will not passed, and the dialog's width won't be reset. It is the reason why only the dialog which is closed to the right edge of the window will have the width not set correctly issue.

Perhaps I didn't make myself clear in the above, so I give another example here.

A dialog was initially placed at the right edge of window, and its offset is `left: 1600, top: 0`, `width: 300`. `woset + that.size.width == that.parentData.width` is true here because the dialog is closed to the right edge of window. The window width is initially set to 1900. To simulate resizing quickly on the left side:

```
var mouseover_event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
    bubbles: true,
    button: 0,
    cancelBubble: false,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: 1600,
    clientY: 300,
    pageX: 1600,
    pageY: 300
});
var mousedown_event = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
    bubbles: true,
    button: 0,
    cancelBubble: false,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: 1600,
    clientY: 300,
    pageX: 1600,
    pageY: 300
});
var mousemove_event = new MouseEvent('mousemove', {
    bubbles: true,
    button: 0,
    cancelBubble: false,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: 1300,
    clientY: 300,
    pageX: 1300,
    pageY: 300
});
var resize_handler = document.querySelector('.ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-w');
resize_handler.dispatchEvent(mouseover_event);
resize_handler.dispatchEvent(mousedown_event);
resize_handler.dispatchEvent(mousemove_event);
```

After dispatch the events, the dialog's position and width should be: `left: 1300; width: 600`.

However, when executing the conditional statement above, `if ( woset + that.size.width >= that.parentData.width ) {`, `that.size.width` was set to be the new dialog width 600, but the `woset` was still the initial offset 1600, `that.parentData.width` is the window's width, 1600 + 600 > 1900, and then the follow statement, `that.size.width = that.parentData.width - woset;` was executed, which sets the dialog's width to nearly the initial width 300. It seems that the dialog was just been moved, not resized. So I think the dialog's width issue was caused by that statement.

The reason I quickly resize the dialog is that I'm writing a script to sync two same page's events, means when an event happened in one page, sends the event detail to the other same page, and then dispatch the same event, just like `element.dispatchEvent(event)` above. For the sake of efficiency, when syncing the drag or resize event, just sync the last mousemove event before the mouseup(it is just the same behavior as quickly resize the dialog).

The jqueryui version I used is 1.11.4.

And my questions:

1. Why to add the conditional statement `if ( woset + that.size.width >= that.parentData.width ) {` and reset the dialog's width `that.size.width = that.parentData.width - woset;`, since `that.size.width` has already been set correctly? And why `woset` was the 'previous value' but not the 'current value'?
2. Are there any workarounds to the dialog's width problem?

Comment: your fiddle does not _make your word clearly_...

Comment: Sorry for that, I have updated my fiddle.https://jsfiddle.net/sangelee/hw62erug/5/embedded/result/  @smnbbrv

Comment: This is clearly a bug in the library. You should try contacting them.

Comment: any word, update, can confirm this bug

Comment: still an issue in UI 1.12.1

Comment: oh looking at your jsfiddle the issues look different